# Google Cloud Billing methods

Tags: google-cloud-platform, billing, google-cloud-billing

I want to use GCE and Google Cloud SQL    but  Google allow only credit/debit cards and bank account

But I have only  a prepaid Mastercard ; there are others methods or third-party company to pay my monthly bill

and thank you

Comment: Billing questions aren't suitable for StackOverflow

Comment: As others said, the question is not suitable for Stack Overflow; please use the Google Group https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/gce-discussion for Google Compute Engine issues that are NOT suitable for this site.

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned in Google's [Billing Support Center](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6293589), prepaid credit cards are not allowed on the Google Cloud Platform. There are no other payment methods accepted other than the one you mentioned.